# How to mock a controller with action that retrieves and stores value using session storage and cookies?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking

I am currently unit testing a controller action method called ResourcesCustomReports by mocking it's controller.

The action method invokes a helper method called GetCurrentTenant which uses this.Request.Cookies["selectedtenant"] to return a value.

In the action I also use session storage to store a key value pair. My question is how do I wire up/mock this action method? Atm I get this error:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.Request.get returned null.'

```
    protected Guid GetCurrentTenant()
    {
        var currentTenant = this.Request.Cookies["selectedtenant"] ?? 
        this.GetUserDefaultTenant().ToString();
        return Guid.Parse(currentTenant);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetCustomDateResourcesReturnsExcelWorkBook()
    {
        var mockPrismRepository = new Mock<IPrismRepository>();
        var mockIlogger = new Mock<ILogger<AzureReportsController>>();
        var mockReportsRepository = new Mock<IReportsRepository>();
        var context = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

        DateTime from = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime to = from.AddDays(30);

        var tenantId = Guid.Parse("3c6b60a7-8d30-4da3-bfdc-00691e899b5f");
        var excelWorkBook = new XLWorkbook();
        var mockReportRepository = new Mock<IReportsRepository>();

        mockReportRepository.Setup(r => r.GetCustomDateResources(tenantId,
        to, from)).Returns(excelWorkBook);
        var azureReportControllerUnderTest = new 
        AzureReportsController(mockIlogger.Object, 
        mockPrismRepository.Object, mockReportRepository.Object);

        azureReportControllerUnderTest.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
        {
            HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(),
        };
        azureReportControllerUnderTest.ControllerContext = context.Object;

        var result = azureReportControllerUnderTest.ResourcesCustomReports(to, from);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);

        excelWorkBook.Dispose();
        azureReportControllerUnderTest.Dispose();
    }

    protected Guid GetCurrentTenant()
    {
     var currentTenant = this.Request.Cookies["selectedtenant"] ? 
     this.GetUserDefaultTenant().ToString();
     return Guid.Parse(currentTenant);
    }


   public IActionResult ResourcesCustomReports(DateTime? startingDate, 
   DateTime endingDate)
    {
        var selectedTenant = this.GetCurrentTenant();
        var fileName = $"resources_report_tenant_id_{selectedTenant}.xlsx";
        var workbook = 
        this.reportsRepository.GetCustomDateResources(selectedTenant, startingDate, 
        endingDate);
        string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook?.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            this.HttpContext.Session.Set(handle, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        return this.Json(new { FileGuid = handle, FileName = fileName });
    }
```

Comment: The client request a cookie from the server.  The server in the response sends a setcookie header and the cookie automatically get sets in the client stores.  You are trying to read the cookie in the request before it is sent.  A test method for a request would connect to a server in the test method.  Then the test method would set the cookie in the reaponse.

Comment: Which part are you referring to? My code works fine I just need to test it and while mocking it I run into issues/errors with session storage and the cookies.

Comment: The code looks like a controller at a server  The client (test method) sends a request to the server. The IActionResult is the body of response from the server.  The response also contains a SetCookie so when the response is received the cookie gets stored into the client stores which is a temp folder in the c:\windows\users\johnsmith.  To test the controller cookies you either have to retrieve the cooks from the stores or parse the response and verify the SetCookie is in the response data.